# HTML Bootstrap Whiteblank ??? at the navbar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my Navbar I have some Problem. I actually dont know how to fix this and dont find anything what can help me because I am really new with bootstrap hope u can help me sry for my bad english.
http://gyazo.com/296c677505bac8ddaea6bd780fc74f41

Here is a download for the full index.html
http://jsbin.com/japokurasu/1/edit?html,css,js

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

remove this div, hope this will works

Comment: If this will works for you, then mark this as an answer.

Comment: WIt dont help the white blank still there

Comment: then share your complete and full html

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly ormatted as code please indent all code by 4 spaces usig the code toolbar button or the ctrl k it say that when i want to do the code at the edit ? :/

Comment: @Rev to your previous comment: is it really that difficult to understand what does the message want you to do??